# The coordinate at which two objects collide

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, coordinate-systems, vectors, velocity

Two people are running and Person 2 is chasing after Person 1. Person 1 starts at (27,20) and is running at 3.5 m/s directly North. Person 2 is starting at (43,19) and running at 8 m/s northwest trying to intercept Person 1. I want to find the angle at which the second person has to take to collide with the first person and at what coordinate. It seems like there are too many unknowns, how would I solve this?

Comment: If it runs northwest the angle is known.

Comment: Northwesterly* - not exactly at 135 degrees

Comment: Northwesterly means to or from northwest.  Still,  the same thing.

Comment: But it is good if the angle is not fixed.  If it were the problem would be overdetermined.  As it is,  you have only one unknown,  the angle.

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to call north the (y) direction and east (x) and assume your given coordinates are (x,y), with θ measured west from north. Then for x, the collision occurs at 27 = 43 – 8 sin(θ) t  and for y:  20 + 3.5 t = 19 + 8 cos(θ) t. This gives two equations for two unknowns.  You might use $sin^2$(θ) + $cos^2$(θ) = 1 to eliminate θ. With (t), you can find the angle.